# Errors executing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I am developing a simple rails app which uses MongoDb as database (with Mongoid). I have been doing my first model in the app, so I want to make tests for it using rspec. After searching, I found rspec-rails and mongoid-rspec gems and I followed their intalling instructions. However, when I execute: ***rails g rspec:install***, I obtain the following error:

```
home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/config/validators/session.rb:99:in `no_database_or_uri?': undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/config/validators/session.rb:45:in `validate_session_database'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/config/validators/session.rb:25:in `block in validate'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/config/validators/session.rb:24:in `each_pair'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/config/validators/session.rb:24:in `validate'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/config.rb:239:in `sessions='
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/config.rb:136:in `load_configuration'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/config.rb:93:in `load!'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid.rb:163:in `load!'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:67:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/jesus/rails_projects/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have been surfing on the Internet but I can't find anything. This are the main configuration files that I have been using:

**config/mongoid.yml**

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: myapp_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
    options:
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: myapp_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

**config/initializers/mongo.rb**

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new( 'localhost', 27017 )
MongoMapper.database = "myapp_#{Rails.env}"

if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    MongoMapper.connection.connect if forked
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.15'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~>4.1.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'mongo', '1.9.2'
gem 'bson_ext', '1.9.2'

gem 'fancybox-rails', "~> 0.2.1" 

gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 3.1.6'

gem 'haml', "~> 4.0.4"

gem 'i18n', '~> 0.6.9'
gem 'i18n-js', '2.1.2'
gem 'mongo-i18n', '~> 0.0.3'

gem 'underscore-rails', '~> 1.5.2'

gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.2'

gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.4.2'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 2.2.8'

gem 'mongoid-paperclip', '~> 0.0.8'

group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14.1"
  gem "mongoid-rspec", "~> 1.11.0"
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

When I try to initialize the server (rails s) or use the console (rails c) I obtain the same error. I have spent lots of hours trying to find the reason but I can't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

PD: Let me know if you need more configuration files, the model, spec_helper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have MongoDB running in port 27017.

Do this to start it:

```
$ mongod
```

Comment: You're right!. But it is not only that. It was working but it hasn't been using config file (/etc/mongodb.conf).

Comment: Sorry for the last answer. Now I can execute tests and they run well. However, when I try to execute rails s or rails c, I obtain the same error.

Comment: Propably the development settings of your `database.yml` are wrong then.

Comment: Do you refer to my mongoid.yml configuration file?

Comment: Finally I found the error. In the configuration file config/initializers/mongo.rb (which appears in the first message), I used the next sentence: MongoMapper.database = "myapp_#{Rails.env}". To solve the problem I only need to use the character '#' before "myapp". Thanks for your help